# Comparing dates on excel

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I know this is probably very simple but I'm struggling to find a formula that works:

I have two worksheets, one showing annual leave for staff and one showing project dates. How can I highlight where an employee's leave will overlap with a project? There's a high number of staff and projects (with various different dates) so I'm hoping not to check them all manually!

Comment: Please provide data, and an attempt to solve this yourself. Check out the [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page.

Comment: Show us what you tried Georox

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the dates that you want to highlight:

[image]

2. Click on **HOME** and then on **Styles** menu area, click **Conditional Formatting**

[image]

3. Select **New Rule**

[image]

4. Select **Format only cells that contain** and you can play with **less than** and **greater than** and put a format for each.

[image]

5. At the end you might have some like this, y use the D2 cell to compare:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple logical `AND` (its easier in Excel if you multiply).

Represent the worked days of an employee on a single line, one cell per day. For a year this is 365(366) days. If employee is here, then its a '1';

Do the same for each project. If project is "one", then its a '1'.

Then on a third sheet (e.g. one sheet per project), you multiply employee per project. Your matches will be represented as `1`, which you can color using formatting functions.

Thus your function for `B2` in your Sheet "*Staff for project 1*" will be:

```
=projs!B$2*staff!B2
```

You can "drag" this formula to have it for the whole year and the whole staff.

Then your `B2` in your Sheet "*Staff for project 2*" will be:

```
=projs!B$3*staff!B2
```

and so on. the `$3` forces the formula to "stay" on the same line when you "drag" the formula.

Here is how it will look:
[image]

Now your problem becomes: how do I make my lists of dates generate tabs `staff` and `projs`